# Why my textbox in the list appear only in the first page?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, page-break

I create a report and I use list which contains a `text box(=Fields!st_crscls.Value)` ,and a Table.

I group by a parameter. But I note that `the textbox` appears only in the **first page**!

All the subsequent pages have no `textbox`.

[image]

Comment: can you show the rdl or whatever other definition / code file?

Comment: the text boxes above the table appear in the first page only !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textboxes don't repeat on their own.

To have a textbox repeat, it should be contained in an repeating item, such as the rows of a table.

From your formula, it sounds like this belongs either in the summary row for a grouping, or in a row in the details group, and you should set the properties of the appropriate group to start a new page on each instance.

Another possibility is to add a Page Header to your report, and place the text box there.

More details on group headers at the top of each page:
Sounds like you just need to display the Group summary row (also called a Total row) on each page. Also sounds like your groups won't span more than one page.
First make sure that you have a Group Total or Summary row.
[image: SSRS Group Total Row]

Then make sure you have a page break between each instance of the group. Sounds like you've already got this, but I would use this setting:

[image: Group Properties-> Page Breaks]

Now the row of the table with `[ClassName]` will always be at the top of a page.

If your groups might span pages, than follow the instructions here.

http://ch1n2.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/how-to-repeat-group-header-on-each-new-page-on-tablix-in-ssrs-2008/

Comment: I have a page header but the text box has different value in each page according to the grouping so i try to put it in the list??

Comment: Could u explain this with a simple example if possible please?

Comment: I started to give a more specific example but I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Have you created a group in SSRS? Does the group have a summary row? Have you tried setting that to repeat on every page? Or have you created a Page Header element in SSRS? (This is a special section of the report canvas.) There are so many possibilities here that creating examples to cover all these could take hours.

Comment: there are students  and i group them by the class , each page has students in **a specific class** (`pagebreakatend = true`), and  i need the class name as a title repeated with each page .thanks a lot

Comment: I added more specifics that should help you out.

Comment: sorry ,i use visual studio 2008 to create my report , so i can't find these windows !!